# Shaded area remains black

Tags: beamer, color

I am working on a course. In the problem set creation, the code worked well and I have the shaded area in gray with the R code in it.
This is the code that worked there:

```
 \documentclass[]{book}
    
    %These tell TeX which packages to use.
    \usepackage{array,epsfig}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{amsxtra}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{mathrsfs}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{adjustbox}
    \usepackage{listings}
    \usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{framed}
    \definecolor{shadecolor}{named}{Gainsboro}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{shaded}

\lstset{language=R,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{DarkGreen},
    otherkeywords={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
    morekeywords={TRUE,FALSE},
    deletekeywords={data,frame,length,as,character},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{DarkGreen},
}
\lstset{columns=fullflexible}
\begin{lstlisting}
# Start by creating a random sample with 10 numbers:

set.seed(123)      

# this will allow everyone to work with the same random 
# sample. To change it, substitute the number in the 
# parenthesis. For this exercise, keep this number.

ex6 <- sample(x = 0:100, size = 10, replace = TRUE) 

# The sample function generates a sample of size 10 
# using numbers from 0 to 100, with replacement. 
\end{lstlisting}
\end{shaded}
```

Result:

[image]

Then, I tried to replicate it in my slides with the following code, but the rectangle remained black. I've tried moving the packages in different positions but nothing seems to give me the same result.

Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}

\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage{ocgx2} %implements PDF Layers
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale21]{ccicons}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{framed}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{named}{Gainsboro}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\subsection{Histogram}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Histogram example}
Using R: 
\begin{shaded}
\lstset{language=R,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{DarkGreen},
    otherkeywords={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
    morekeywords={TRUE,FALSE},
    deletekeywords={data,frame,length,as,character},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{DarkGreen},
}
\lstset{columns=fullflexible}
\begin{lstlisting}
# From the integers 0:100, draw 20 numbers
set.seed(3640)
Sample <- sample(x = 0:100, size = 25, replace = TRUE)
df <- c(Sample)
df
\end{lstlisting}
\end{shaded}
\end{frame}
```

Result:

[image]

Is there any way I could make it get gray instead of black?

Comment: Your code is not complete and may give compilation errors.

Comment: Use `xcolor={svgnames}` as option to the document class instead of loading `xcolor` with options. This will only result in an option clash and the relevant colors won't be used correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you just add the following to your lstsettings?

```
backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray}
```

And also getting rid of `\begin{shaded}` and `\end{shaded}` did the trick for me:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

Beamer automatically loads the `xcolor` package. You can't load it again with conflicting options.

Instead you can tell beamer which options you want with the following class option: `\documentclass[xcolor={svgnames}]{beamer}`

---

Some other comments:

- don't load packages multiple times. You risk running into exactly such option conflicts which caused the error with your background colour
- you don't need to load the `hyperref` and `graphicx` packages, beamer loads them for you
- don't use `fancyhdr` with beamer, beamer has its own mechanism for head- and footlines
- instead of using `multicol`, I'd rather use beamer's own column mechanism

---

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor=svgnames]{beamer}

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage{ocgx2} %implements PDF Layers
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ccicons}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{adjustbox} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\usepackage{xspace}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage[]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{framed}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{named}{Gainsboro}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Histogram}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Histogram example}
Using R: 
\begin{shaded}
\lstset{language=R,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{DarkGreen},
    otherkeywords={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
    morekeywords={TRUE,FALSE},
    deletekeywords={data,frame,length,as,character},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{DarkGreen},
}
\lstset{columns=fullflexible}
\begin{lstlisting}
# From the integers 0:100, draw 20 numbers
set.seed(3640)
Sample <- sample(x = 0:100, size = 25, replace = TRUE)
df <- c(Sample)
df
\end{lstlisting}
\end{shaded}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry for this dumb question but I am beginning my journey learning R and LaTeX. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @bmt You're welcome!